# How to stop LibGDX InputProcessor recognizing enter key

Tags: input, libgdx

Im making a game with Libgdx and ive noticed that pressing enter key while using an InputProcessor automatically adds new line. Funnily enough, i dont want this, i want it to call my own method. How would i do this?

Currently when i press enter, which i detect using polling, i have it set to do the following

*print the user input to console
*print "1"
*print "2"

it prints

*user input*
AN EMPTY LINE
1
2

theres a gap after *userinput* so ive concluded that its making a new line, as using polling rather than inputprocessor doesnt do this!

(1 and 2 was to compare the spacing between lines to see whether it was actually making a new line. When typing "omg why" i get this result in console

http://puu.sh/5x0kw.png

Comment: Please provide a bit more context about what your app is doing with the input.  Where are you seeing a "new line"?

Comment: @P.T. ive added this info to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using keyUp. Previously i was using charTyped